# How to transition subviews in SwiftUI using matchedGeometryEffect?

Tags: view, swiftui, transition

I have a number of `SwapItem` structs, each with a child `SwapItemChild`. Then, using a `ForEach` of SwiftUI, I would like to display the name of each `SwapItem`, called the item view, containing also a circle in the color of its respective `SwapItemChild`, called the child view. Subsequently, I would like to swap the children of two items, and have the respective child views change places animated. This was inspired by other examples of this effect by [this extensive tutorial](https://swiftui-lab.com/matchedgeometryeffect-part2), but not specifically the children view swapping.

I attempt to do so using a `matchedGeometryEffect` identifying each child view by the id of the respective `SwapItemChild`. However, this leads to a jumpy animation, where only the top child view moves down, whereas the bottom child view instantaneously jumps to the top.

The functional example code is as follows.

```
// MARK: - Model
struct SwapItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    var child: SwapItemChild
}

struct SwapItemChild: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let color: Color
}

class SwapItemStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var items = [SwapItem(name: "Task 1", child: SwapItemChild(color: .red)),
                                         SwapItem(name: "Task 2", child: SwapItemChild(color: .orange))]
    
    func swapOuterChildren(){
        let tmpChild = items[0].child
        items[0].child = items[1].child
        items[1].child = tmpChild
    }
}

// MARK: - View
struct SwapTestView: View {
    @StateObject private var swapItemStore = SwapItemStore()
    @Namespace private var SwapViewNS
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50.0) {
            Button(action: swapItemStore.swapOuterChildren){
                Text("Swap outer children")
                    .font(.title)
            }
            
            VStack(spacing: 150.0) {
                ForEach(swapItemStore.items){ item in
                    SwapTestItemView(item: item, ns: SwapViewNS)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SwapTestItemView: View {
    let item: SwapItem
    let ns: Namespace.ID
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(item.child.color)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: item.child.id, in: ns)
                .animation(.spring())
            
            Text(item.name)
        }
    }
}
```

What is the correct implementation of `matchedGeometryEffect` to have these child views swapping places seamlessly?

Comment: This is not the way how this tool works. The `matchedGeometryEffect` works between two views with same ID in *different* hierarchies. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/64414233/12299030.

Comment: I did not interpret that restriction from the documentation. Apple: "If inserting a view in the same transaction that another view with the same key is removed, the system will interpolate their frame rectangles in window space to make it appear that there is a single view moving from its old position to its new position.".
I thought that my approach is inserting a subview in a new place and removing it from the old place, thus should be usable with `matchedGeometryEffect`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have already encountered this kind of problem, try this :

```
ForEach(swapItemStore.items, id: \.self.child.id)
```

[image: swap animation]

Another way :

```
struct SwapItem: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    var child: SwapItemChild
}

struct SwapItemChild: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let color: Color
}
```

with :

```
ForEach(swapItemStore.items, id: \.self)
```

See : https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/why-does-self-work-for-foreach

Comment: Thanks! Am I correct in understanding that this way, the rows in the list are identified by SwiftUI (for animation etc.) by _both_ the `SwapItem` and `SwapItemChild`? This would then different from my original implementation, where they are only identified by `SwapItem`. Is your animation then working correctly because essentially both rows are 'replaced', that is no rows remain with the same identifier, rather than retaining the same identifier after swapping like in my implementation? Does anyone know why this produces the correct frame interpolation?