# SwiftUI matchedGeometry + LazyVStack = crash

Tags: animation, swiftui

It took me hours to construct this example, and I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong or there is a bug crashing the app when using `matchedGeometry` + `LazyVStack`.

In the video below the app crashed when I click on third rectangle (which was not visible when the app started). Crash disappears if I replace `LazyVStack` with `VStack`, but obviously I want to lazy load my things.

Xcode version: Version 12.0.1 (12A7300)

[image]

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Namespace var namespace
    @State var selected: Int?


    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack { 
                Text("Cool rectangles")
                
                if selected == nil {
                    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                        BoxList(namespace: namespace, selected: $selected)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if let id = selected {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: id, in: namespace)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation{
                            selected = nil
                        }
                    }

            }

        }
    }
}

struct BoxList: View {
    let namespace: Namespace.ID
    @Binding var selected: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVStack {
            ForEach(0..<10){ item in
                Rectangle()
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: item, in: namespace)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation {
                            selected = item
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you destroy `ScrollView` breaking matched layout.

Here is fixed variant. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Namespace var namespace
    @State var selected: Int?


    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Cool rectangles")
                
                  ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                        BoxList(namespace: namespace, selected: $selected)
                  }.opacity(selected == nil ? 1 : 0)
            } // << or place here opacity modifier here
            
            if let id = selected {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: id, in: namespace)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation{
                            selected = nil
                        }
                    }

            }

        }
    }
}

struct BoxList: View {
    let namespace: Namespace.ID
    @Binding var selected: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVStack {
            ForEach(0..<10){ item in
                    if item == selected {
                Color.clear     // placeholder to avoid duplicate match id run-time warning
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    } else {
                Rectangle()
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: item, in: namespace)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation {
                            selected = item
                        }
                    }
                        }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but why destroying views should be a problem? Surely people often wanna show/hide views on condition. It would seem that the more natural way use if/else to show views rather than use opacity?

Comment: It is not about generic show/hide and it, `if` is actually adds/removes views, but the issue is about `matchedGeometryEffect` which requires both matched with same id views to be present, but by removing ScrollView you destroy on of matched paired views. That's the reason.