# How can I do a MatchedGeometryEffect animation?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Do you have any approach about how to scale ( with MatchedGeometryEffect ) my 'MealTabView' ( the cells that you can see in the picture ) so that it can fill an entire view ? :

[image]

Here's the source code for the 'cells' that you can see :

```
struct MealTabView:View{


var meal: Meal

@Binding var selectedBtn: [Int]
var body: some View{
    ZStack{
        
        Button(action: {
            if selectedBtn.contains(self.meal.id){
                selectedBtn.remove(at: selectedBtn.firstIndex(of: self.meal.id)!)
            } else{
                selectedBtn.append(self.meal.id)
            }
            
            
            
        }, label: {
            ZStack(alignment:.center){
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 200)
                    .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.1), radius: 5)
                    .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                                .stroke(selectedBtn.contains(self.meal.id) ? Color.black : Color.white, lineWidth: 4)
                        )
                
                VStack(alignment:.center){
                    switch meal.id { // for the future images
                    
                    default:
                        Image("meal")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                            .padding(.top,30)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Text(meal.title)
                        .padding(.bottom,20)
                        .wotfard(size: 20) // custom modifier for a special font
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
                
            }.frame(width: 150, height: 200)
        })
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64414233/12299030?

Comment: Yes a bit @Asperi, but I m looking for a scale effect. My "cell" will represents a meal and I want this "cell" to scale so that you can see more informations about the meal

Comment: Can you please help me @Asperi I'm so lost 